# Vertically scrollable td in an HTML table does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a fiddle below that works as I would expect in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox.

I have two elements in a table. The content of the left element is very short, the content of the other is very long. I want the two elements to be displayed as though they are the same size in the table, and I want the longer one to have a scrollbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/rju1os7m/1/

Chrome (good):

[image: Chrome]

Firefox (bad):

[image: Firefox]

HTML:

```
<body>
<table border="2" width="200px" height="100px">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      This is a short td
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <div style="overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%;">
        This is a really long td with a lot of text that you have to scroll through it's great
        it's really incredible very cool indeed yes alright everybody thank you
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using

```
{height:100px;}
```

for the < div>.

Comment: I don't understand why that works when "100%" didn't, but thanks! My only complaint is that this creates a horizontal scrollbar in Firefox (but not in Chrome), but I can work around that separately

Comment: probably a glitch in Firefox!